# Cannot access Google Spreadsheet metadata by API

Tags: php, permissions, google-sheets-api

I have this code that tries to retrieve all data from a sheet , including metadata:

```
$response = $this->spreadsheet_service->spreadsheets->get($this->spreadsheet_id, ['ranges' => $sheet_name ]);
$sheetData = $response->getSheets();
foreach ($sheetData as $sheet) {
                    echo "sheet:";
                    var_dump($sheet);
                    $data = $sheet->getData();   
                    echo "sheet Data:";
                    var_dump($data);
                    die; 
}
```

The dump of `$sheet` shows me an object with `rowCount = 996` , which means it's not empty. But the dump of `$data` shows:

```
sheet Data:array(0) { }
```

If i use `$this->spreadsheet_service->spreadsheets_values` , i can get all the values correctly , but i need a way to get metadata too , like each cell's last update time and coordinates.
Maybe with my API credentials i cannot access metadata , that's why the code above won't work.
Is there a permission i need to grant to my API user ? Or what else could be the problem?
Thanks

Comment: I think that unfortunately, in the current stage, `each cell's last update` of `i can get all the values correctly , but i need a way to get metadata too , like each cell's last update and coordinates.` cannot be achieved using Sheets API.

Comment: @Tanaike source pls? Also i fixed my post: "each cell's last update time" , not the update contents. Maybe you believed i want to retrieve the edited text , not the timestamp . If you are sure it's not supported by the current API , you want to post your comment as an answer

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `source pls?`, it can be seen at [this official document](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet). Here, you can see all properties returned from Sheets API. You can see that there is no property for the last updated time of cells. About `each cell's last update time`, I understood that you might have wanted to retrieve the last updated time of each cell. If my understanding is correct, unfortunately, this cannot be retrieved by Sheets API. But, if I misunderstood your question and reply, please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my quick research , i've found out it's possible to achieve my goal by AppScripts + webhooks: https://medium.com/@eyalgershon/sending-a-webhook-for-new-or-updated-rows-in-google-sheets-e0c9d6a8cb45

In the AppScript function , one can get any metadata and pass it to the webhook , like current time , coordinates , etc.